# Почему не работает `std::pmr::string`?

Tags: c++, строки

Почему не работает `std::pmr::string`? https://godbolt.org/z/naYvrYxGq

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::pmr::string x = "test";
}
```

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:80:24:
> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class
> std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator'    80 |  rebind<_CharT>::other
> _Char_alloc_type;
> |

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лечится включением `#include <memory_resource>` https://godbolt.org/z/Wr4661bY9 Хотя почему не работает прямо так - надо разбираться...

Comment: @user7860670 видимо, только forward declaration добавили, чтобы не захломлять string хедер. Почему-то в документации нет этого только

Answer (score 0):

В хедеры контейнеров и прочих часто используемых вещей добавили только forward declarations для `polymorphic_allocator`. Например, в векторе `libstdc++`:

```
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
  namespace pmr {
    template<typename _Tp> class polymorphic_allocator;
    template<typename _Tp>
      using vector = std::vector<_Tp, polymorphic_allocator<_Tp>>;
  } // namespace pmr
```

Непонятно только, почему это не задокументировано в header synopsis только https://eel.is/c++draft/string.syn.

То есть если действительно хочешь использовать `std::pmr::string`, надо добавить `<memory_resource>`. Если не хочешь, то не будет оверхеда от простого включения `<string>`.